# iphone in app purchase "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, storekit, itunes-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone Store Kit “Cannot connect to iTunes Store”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359739/iphone-store-kit-cannot-connect-to-itunes-store)

i am implementing in app purchase when i requesting the payment am getting bellow error.

Transaction Error: Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo=0x2dcf40 {NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}

Here some times the error code will be 1004. so i cant do the transaction.

in some times it displaying a warning like " has failed the purchase process." ,but still the purchase process is working fine..

am i doing something wrong... or any solution for this problem..?

Thanks

Comment: I have tried all what I can to deal with this issue. And finally I find the key. Try with another device to test the iAP if your device's iOS is iOS13.4.x！！！And I upgrade this ”broken“ device's OS version to iOS14.0.1, iAP works like a charm.

Answer (score 11):

There are several recommendations in this discussion: http://www.everythingicafe.com/forum/threads/cannot-connect-to-itunes-store.11586/

Thought most I tried were unsuccessful.  I had the best luck signing out of my test account and trying again.

iPad/iPhone -> Setting -> Store -> (select account) -> Sign Out

Then try again.

Comment: Hi Matt: You method works. But my concern is when the app goes alive, does the user have to logout store too in order to do purchase. If that is the case, we need found solution to fix it.

Comment: Woohoo, this 'fixed' it for me :D Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I get this error a lot on the live app store. I still have a lot of purchases go through, but I get several hundred of these errors a week and no idea why...

Comment: @PsychoDad - might be users trying to spoof In-App purchases using saved sessions. I get that a lot, too.

Comment: @YiminRong Hmmm. Interesting.

Answer (score 4):

In my project i had not set the `CFBundleVersion`. After giving it a value in the project settings purchasing worked. Retrieving the list of products also worked with the missing CFBundleVersion.

Apple also states this in their Technote regarding IAP: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2259/_index.html

Comment: The same for me. Nice localised error for such case :(

Comment: Thank you, you saved me two hours to find what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I have two different iTunes Connect accounts, and my problem was I was using the wrong Test User account.

It wasn't obvious that this is what was wrong as you can login just fine with the wrong account.  The error message given to the user was related to the item was already purchased but not downloaded.  Using the correct account's test user resolved the issue.