# How to fix In app purchase error "Transaction error: Cannot connect to iTunes Store code 0 "?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone Store Kit “Cannot connect to iTunes Store”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359739/iphone-store-kit-cannot-connect-to-itunes-store)

I found error when I buy something. It not show prompt to login and return error "Transaction error: Cannot connect to iTunes Store code 0 " . But I try to create new project and use the same code for In-app purchase ,it worked!! . 
I try to re-install,delete app and logout from store, I ensure the productIdentifier is correct. Anyone have any idea ,tell me please.

Comment: I have met similar error on jailbroken device. On another "clear" one  there were no errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a server side issue and seems to be associated with the test account where the product becomes "stuck".

My workaround is to reset the password on the test account as this seems to "reboot" the account.