# In app purchase product not showing up in productsRequest?

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

I have 4 in-app purchases setup, all working well. I've added a fifth one, same implementation as the others. It was approved, looks fine in itunes connect. All are non-consumables.

But in my SKProductsRequestDelegate, I don't get its product ID here:

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response 
{

    NSArray* skProducts = response.products;
    for (SKProduct* skProduct in skProducts) {
        // I don't see its product ID here, the others all appear fine.
    }
}
```

the others all show up ok. The item was approved more than 24 hours ago. Any idea why it might not be coming back from apple as part of that request? Again, everything looks ok in itunes connect.

Thanks

Comment: Paid contracts were recently updated, did you agree to the new one?

Comment: Yeah it says they're all in effect (there are two, the "All" for paid apps, and the "World" one for free apps).

Comment: Double check your productIdentifier and delete the app from simulator/device?  Other than that, I'd say wait another day and see if it doesn't show up.

Comment: Ok waited a few more days and still not coming down in the productsRequest response. The item is definitely approved and ready for sale in itunesconnect. Do I have to contact apple somehow at this point :\

Answer (score 2):

I did as mentioned by Davis G. on the comments and as dcRay answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14638935/676822).

1. Make sure you're testing on a real device
2. In your apps Info.plist file, check if Bundle Identifier (e.g. com.company.appname) matches the one in iTunes Connect