# IAP bug in app store review, unable to reproduce

Tags: ios, objective-c

I recently submitted an update to my app that contains new in-app purchases. The update was rejected due to a "bug" where the app shows a message saying there are no products available for purchase. This message is only shown when SKProductsResponse returns an empty products array.

This is where I'm confused, because the exact same version installed on my phone works perfectly; the product information is received and displayed correctly with no error. These products showed 'waiting for review' in iTunesConnect before the review and now show 'developer action needed'.

I'm unsure how to proceed, I have written back to them saying that I don't think it's a bug, no response yet.

Is it possible at the time they were reviewing the app that the SKProductsResponse temporarily failed to return the products for some reason? Or is there possibly some difference between the app store review version and my version? If so how can I ensure that my version behaves in the same way?

Comment: check this:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138972/iphone-in-app-purchase-response-products-are-still-empty-please-help

Comment: That's not my issue because in my installation of the app it works fine. But the version the app review team is using did not retrieve the products correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was definitely an Apple bug. They eventually approved the original version I submitted after sending them a message explaining what was going on.